# Quaternions in CLAPACK or an Alternate C Style Quaternion Library

Tags: c, linear-algebra, quaternions

I am porting a set of spatial computations to an embedded environment that essentially compiles and runs C code.

I have replaced a number of the linear algebra functions that previously used VNL (a templated C++ library that will not work on the new platform) with CBLAS and CLAPACK.  Their API (all parameters are pointers, no templates) is perfect for what I am doing.

The catch, however, is I do not see quaternion based functions anywhere in the CLAPACK Users Guide.  Am I missing a section and there is quaternion support somewhere?  If so, please point me to the functions.  Specifically, I'm looking for inverse, multiplication, and conversion to and from euler angles and 3x3 matrices.

If there is not this kind of support in CLAPACK, is there another library with similar design characteristics that does quaternion math?

Comment: cant a quaternion be interpreted as a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: Yes, and converting the existing code to rotation matrices may be possible, but is not preferable.  Firstly, one of our external inputs feeds quaternions to our API, so there will have to be some level of support and conversion.  Secondly, I believe there is a storage size and performance advantages in rotational calculations when using quaternions over rotational matrices. Here is a more information, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Performance_comparisons_with_other_rotation_methods.

Comment: Not really an answer, but can't you not come up with this yourself and expose it through a BLAS/LAPACK-like API. Those few functions (quaternion algebra, transformation of vectors, conversion to other representations) shouldn't be that hard or tedious to implement. I guess it is not in LAPACK as it is only of interest to a smaller group of people (mechanics and graphics people that are, maybe some physicians, or was it physicists?) and it doesn't really belong to classical linear algebra, let aside numerical linear algebra, I think.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I'm looking at doing that right now, in fact.  I'm actually considering using the functions in VNL as a starting point, and replacing any VNL math with CLAPACK calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PDF seems to indicate that quaternion support was not planned in LAPACK.  I suppose it is safe to assume CLAPACK would be the same.

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn106.pdf

I still have not found a replacement or supplementary library that does support quaternions.

EDIT:

Found CQRLib, an ANSI C quaternion library.  It allocates variables to the stack (a problem on my architecture), so I'll have to refactor that.  But otherwise it looks like it should work.

http://cqrlib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: CQRLib seems to cover what I need.  I'll reselect someone else's answer if new information is added, but for now, using CLAPACK for all linear algebra besides quaternions and adding in CQR to cover that gap is my solution.